# Can I make paredit work with only braces {…} instead of other parens?

Tags: paredit

I'm trying to create `paredit` functionality for TeX modes and I'd *really* like to avoid actually rewriting `paredit.el`.  (I've spent a good portion of the day doing this with no significant progress.)

I had figured `paredit` would simply look at the syntax table for its open/close paren bits, but this appears to not be the case.  Is there a way to alter `paredit` variables to get the result I need, or is there perhaps another, more minimalistic minor mode I can use?

Comment: Maybe you need to edit `paredit-commands`?

Comment: There are basically only 2-3 commands that can apply to TeX outside of electric pairs (which you can have without paredit). Might as well just write down these 2-3 commands.

Comment: @abo-abo In the context of a document, sure. In the context of `expl3`? There are…weird things.